# Replace bold with semibold using `kpfonts`

Tags: bold, kpfonts

I'm using `kpfonts` to compile a pdf using `PDFLaTeX`, and I generally like the results. But I find the bold font to be too... bold. I know `kpfonts` has a semibold variant, but I cannot find a way to replace all instances of bold font with semibold.

Is there a way to output semibold font globally in all instances where bold formatting is used (e.g., chapter/section headings and when using `\textbf`) without using `fontspec`, `XeLaTeX`, etc.?

Here's an MWE, if it helps:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter name}
    Here is some random text 1234567890...Here is some \textbf{random text in bold} 1234567890...
    \section{Section name}
    Here is some random text 1234567890...Here is some \textbf{random text in bold} 1234567890...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try `\usepackage[light]{kpfonts}`

Comment: @SimonDispa Unfortunately, that makes the normal font too light. I would like to use semibold wherever bold formatting is applied, and leave all other formatting untouched.

Comment: Please tell us whether you use pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX to compile your document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change `\bfdefault` to `sb`. To load the extra weights you need the `rmx` option of kpfonts (see page 4 of the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/kpfonts/doc/kpfonts.pdf)). As @egreg mentions in the comments, you should also use `\DeclareMathAlphabet` to make `\mathbf` use semibold.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[rmx]{kpfonts}

\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{sb}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{\bfdefault}{n}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter name}
    Here is some random text 1234567890...Here is some \textbf{random text in bold} 1234567890...
    \section{Section name}
    Here is some random text 1234567890...Here is some \textbf{random text in bold} 1234567890...
\end{document}
```

[image: semibold]

Comment: You also want to reset `\mathbf` with `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{\bfdefault}{n}` otherwise the standard `b` font would be used.

Comment: Good point. Added to answer